# Pandas means in column for subset in another column

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a dataframe called houses:

```
         transaction_id  house_id    date_sale  sale_price boolean_2015  \
    0                     1         1  31 Mar 2016    £880,000         True   
    3                     4         2  31 Mar 2016    £450,000         True   
    4                     5         3  31 Mar 2016    £680,000         True   
    6                     7         4  31 Mar 2016  £1,850,000         True  
               postcode  
    0           EC2Y  
    3           EC2Y  
    4           EC1Y  
    6           EC2Y
```

and I was wondering how to compute averages of sale_price based on each postcode
so the output is

```
           Average
0 EC1Y     £123220
1 EC2Y     £434930
```

I did this with `averages = data.groupby(['postcode'], as_index=False).mean()`
 but this did not return sale_price
any thoughts?

Comment: first you'll need to clean up `sale_price` column and cast it to numeric dtype...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `£,` to empty string and then convert [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) column `sale_price`. Last cast to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) if need add `£` to column `sale_price`:

```
data.sale_price = pd.to_numeric(data.sale_price.str.replace('[£,]',''))
averages = data.groupby(['postcode'], as_index=False)['sale_price'].mean()
averages.sale_price = '£' + averages.sale_price.astype(str) 
print (averages)
  postcode sale_price
0     EC1Y    £680000
1     EC2Y   £1060000
```